# Cocos2d not getting the texture which is added to CCTextureCache using thread

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I convert the image into texture in a thread using the following line of code to reduce the image to texture converting time.

[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"imageName"];

But when i retrieve this image from cache i am getting a blank image. If i am calling the above line of code in main thread i am getting the image.

Answer (score 1):

There is function in [`- (void)addImageAsync:(NSString *)filename target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0-rc/interface_c_c_texture_cache.html#a19844e2980e63b366605eaa97239ba59) I suggest you either use this function or try reading how this function is using thread.